# Weird Play Store crash related to features not used by my Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I am trying to publish a flutter app to Google Play store. Google internal testing is posting this ANR crash only on "AQUOS sense2 SH-01L - DOCOMO" device (sdk 28).

Error message mentions `quicksearchbox`, `LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED`, `TikTok`, which is weird as my app does not use any social media, accounts/logins, or search. Watching the video, the app is working, I do not see it crash.

It is also weird that I would get this only on one of many devices they test with. If I did something wrong in code, this would affect all devices (unless due to low memory or small screen or something like that which does not seem to be the case here).

How can I troubleshoot this?

```
ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search;PID: 15056;Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared in the next release although I did not change anything significant. Probably was just a glitch on Google end.